# Getting pairwise comparisons from a pandas dataframe from a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pairwise

I have a dataframe with pairwise comparisons (comparing "query"and "reference"), a distance column and some columns with metadata. I made a selection and created a new dataframe from the main dataframe.

I want all pairwise comparisons of the 19 elements that are in the "query" column of the new dataframe. Then I want to get those elements where one element is present in the "query" column and another that is present in the "reference" column of the main dataframe.

So, what I tried is (in Python 3.10.6, Pandas 1.5.0):

```
def metadata_def_epi(df_metadata, df_selection_ur):

    df_selection_ur_list = df_selection_ur["query"].values.tolist()
    
    mask = df_metadata["query"].isin(df_selection_ur_list) & df_metadata["reference"].isin(df_selection_ur_list)
    
    df_out = df_metadata[mask]

return df_out
```

It works as intended, BUT I only get 136 pairwise comparisons while I'm expecting 171 (pairwise comparisons = n(n-1)/2).

Am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

### EDIT

@itprorh66, here is an example of my data:
Main dataframe:

| FIELD1 | query | reference | Core | Accessory | pmatch | patient_id_query | Collection_date_query | instelling_query | locatie_query | afdeling_query | patient_id_reference | Collection_date_reference | instelling_reference | locatie_reference | afdeling_reference | Cdate_query | Cdate_reference | epi_link_id | snp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ASM1421713v1_genomic | ASM1527755v1_genomic | 0,000312388 | 0,052548587 | 0,938905646 | pt4 | 17-aug-2020 | AP | 00 | 00 | pt5 | 7-nov-2020 | HK | 00 | 00 | 17-aug-2020 | 7-nov-2020 | Unrelated | 70 |
| 1 | ASM1421713v1_genomic | ASM1930313v1_genomic | 0,002514303 | 0,15178698 | 0,788494326 | pt4 | 17-aug-2020 | AP | 00 | 00 | pt6 | 21-jul-2021 | LA | 00 | 00 | 17-aug-2020 | 21-jul-2021 | Unrelated | 3608 |
| 2 | ASM1421713v1_genomic | ASM194037v1_genomic | 0,000102997 | 0,080629885 | 0,916627997 | pt4 | 17-aug-2020 | AP | 00 | 00 | pt2 | 9-jan-2017 | CP | 00 | 00 | 17-aug-2020 | 9-jan-2017 | Unrelated | 103 |
| 3 | ASM1421713v1_genomic | ASM2008964v1_genomic | 0,004278481 | 0,124020875 | 0,773557592 | pt4 | 17-aug-2020 | AP | 00 | 00 | pt7 | 21-sep-2021 | NO | 00 | 00 | 17-aug-2020 | 21-sep-2021 | Unrelated | 7313 |
| 4 | ASM1421713v1_genomic | ASM2491733v1_genomic | 0,000498295 | 0,08597058 | 0,900912922 | pt4 | 17-aug-2020 | AP | 00 | 00 | pt8 | 4-sep-2022 | TX | 00 | 00 | 17-aug-2020 | 4-sep-2022 | Unrelated | 145 |
| 5 | ASM1421713v1_genomic | ASM2539267v1_genomic | 0,000156939 | 0,10040438 | 0,895510335 | pt4 | 17-aug-2020 | AP | 00 | 00 | pt9 | 23-sep-2022 | RA | 00 | 00 | 17-aug-2020 | 23-sep-2022 | Unrelated | 83 |
| 6 | ASM1421713v1_genomic | ASM972006v1_genomic | 0,000523388 | 0,08677614 | 0,899463797 | pt4 | 17-aug-2020 | AP | 00 | 00 | pt3 | 27-nov-2017 | US | 00 | 00 | 17-aug-2020 | 27-nov-2017 | Unrelated | 96 |

Input of a list of query IDs = [ASM1527755v1_genomic, ASM1930313v1_genomic, ASM194037v1_genomic, ASM2008964v1_genomic]

Expected output:
Similar table as the main dataframe, but than only the selection where one of the elements of my input list is in "query" and another one in the "reference" column.

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data nor any of the code that you have written that produces your problem. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: @itprorh66 I added a few example rows to the question, I hope this clarifies my question?

Comment: So do I understand that you desire an output which selects from the input df if the selection criterion is in the query column or the reference column?

Comment: Yes basically I want the pairwise comparisons with an ID that is in my selection (a list of ID's).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to the `&` operator used in your mask statement.  This will result in selecting rows which contain one or more of the selection criteria in both the query and reference columns.

to fix this issue rewrite your function as shown below:

```
def metadata_def_epi(df_metadata, df_selection_ur):

    df_selection_ur_list = df_selection_ur["query"].values.tolist()
    # Note change in the mask statement from & to | operator
    mask = df_metadata["query"].isin(df_selection_ur_list) | df_metadata["reference"].isin(df_selection_ur_list)
    
    df_out = df_metadata[mask]

return df_out
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I phrased my question wrong. But I do not want one of my ID's to be in query or in reference, but for example in my list I have: [ID1, ID2, ID3]. Then I want ID1 in query and ID2 in reference, ID1 in query and ID3 in reference, ID2 in query and ID3 in reference

Comment: So given a list of selection options ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3']  you want the combinations ('ID1', 'ID2'), ('ID1', 'ID3'), ('ID2', 'ID3') where the first tuple entry refers to the Query column and the second refers to the Reference column, but you don't want the inverse where the first refers to the Query column and the second refers to the Reference column?

Comment: It doesn't really matter if the tuples are inversed, as long as I get all the possible combinations of the list of selection options ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3']

Comment: Oay, I am officially confused.  Can you provide an example that illustrates what your end frame looks like?  Hopefully that will clarify